# How to find this series interval of convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

$\sum _ { n = 0 } ^ { \infty } ((pn)!/(n!)^p)x^n$ then 
I find the interval of convergence is $(-1/p^p,1/p^p)$.
But I can't know if when $x=-1/p^p$ the power series is convergent or divergent or not,
and $x=1/p^p$, too